# How to determine if a list of words exists adjacent to each other in a string?

Tags: python, string, substring

I have a sentence and a list of substrings. How can I check the exact substring occurs in that sentence or not?

For example:

```
Credit card customers will be allowed interest-free installment plans for all school fee payments as well as grocery purchases with no processing fees for up to six months.
```

and now I have a list of words

```
["credit card customers","school fee payment","six months"].
```

How can I check if these substrings exist in above string?

Comment: read this https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-check-if-python-string-contains-another-string

Comment: how would you do it either on paper or in your head?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
string = 'Credit card customers will be allowed interest-free installment plans for all school fee payments as well as grocery purchases with no processing fees for up to six months.'
listing = ["credit card customers","school fee payment","six months"]

def adj_or_not(index1,index2):
    if listing[index1] + listing[index2] in string:
        return True
    else:
        return False

adj_or_not(0,1)
```

Output:

```
False
```